# PHP array check all values is equal

Tags: php, arrays

```
 array
  0 => 
    array
      'point' => string '2' 
  1 => 
    array 
      'point' => string '4' 
  2 => 
    array 
      'point' => string '1'
```

I need checking values of 'point' in above array, if all values of 'point' is '4' it will return true as below array.

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'point' => string '4'
  1 => 
    array
      'point' => string '4'
  2 => 
    array
      'point' => string '4'
```

Comment: only if whole array consist of only point =>4?

Comment: `function checkArray($myArray) { $result = array_unique(array_column($myArray, 'status_id')); return (count($result) == 1 && $result[0] == '4'); }`

Comment: @Toumash Yes all values point '4'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use 2 statements fomr PHP. [**if**](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php) and [**for**](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php).

I used following script to test it (you can choose one of the loops(for or foreach))

```
$test = array(array('point' => 4), array('point' => 4));

function checkArrayForPointValue($array, $expectedValue)
{
    $ok = true;
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
        if ($array[$i]['point'] != $expectedValue) {
            $ok = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    // choose one of them

    foreach ($array as $element) {
        if ($element['point'] != $expectedValue) {
            $ok = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return $ok;
}

print(checkArrayForPointValue($test, '4') ? 'yay' : 'not yay');
```

Answer (score 0):

Compare each value in a foreach :

```
function arrayComparePoint($array) {
$valueCompare = $array[0]['point'];
    foreach ($array as $arrayPoint) {
        foreach ($arrayPoint as $point) {
            if ($valueCompare != $point) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use as

```
function checkArray($myArray) {
    $result = array_unique(array_column($myArray, 'point'));
    return (count($result) == 1 && $result[0] == '4') ? "true" : "false";
}
echo checkArray($myArray);
```